# visualforce+aws upload in IE - error unsupported body payload object

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, visualforce

I am trying to upload files into AWS S3 using `bucket.upload()` method in Javascript. It is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but showing the below error in IE 10+.

> Error : Unsupported body payload object.

Any help on this scenario?

Comment: What have you tried to solve it yourself?